# Flutter find the executable for `where` error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hello i am new in flutter and android programming. I have install flutter git and android studio. However,when i run `flutter doctor` i got this error. I tried all possible solutions that is in here and youtube.

[image]

Everything was deleted and installed again and again. It still says the same error

Comment: The issue was fixed. You have to add PATH variable to this  "C:\Windows\System32". That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add PATH environment in your system.

For the windows: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path

For the mac: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path